How can I move an image into the iOS device gallery before starting Katalon iOS test automation?
Can someone help automate the following scenario?
Scenario: I need to register a user using a QR code generated by the system.
Precondition: I need to automate the step of moving a QR code PNG file into my iOS device gallery before starting the test case.
How can I automate this process?
I have tried many ways;
1st option
Mobile.pushFile("device-location",new File("local-machine-file-path"))
2nd option
File imageFile=new File("Resources/patients_qr/dev_study_1/client-9923-qr.jpg");
driver.pushFile("/Documents/client-9923-qr.jpg", imageFile)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
